# SQL Server : Insert into table a count of records

Tags: insert, count, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to insert a count but I get and error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SET'.

Am I going about this the wrong way?

```
INSERT INTO Timestamp_ActiveReferralscopy
   SET count = (select count(HashID) 
         from [dbo].[T_PTID]
   where date_of_Death is null AND Deduction_Date is null)
```

Comment: FYI, `SET` is an `UPDATE` keyword - when you are first creating records, there is no field to `SET` the value of, as that record does not exist yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you're looking for?

```
    INSERT INTO Timestamp_ActiveReferralscopy (count)
    select count(HashID) from [dbo].[T_PTID]    
    where date_of_Death is null AND Deduction_Date is null
```

....

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: Yes just figured out the same as you got. Thanks Worked a treat!